# Linking fails when trying to link a nasm object file

Tags: gcc, x86, nasm, x86-64, ld

I have this simple program to compute the square root of a floating point number

```
global main
extern printf
section .data
        float_t db '%f',0x0
        val dq 123.45
        res dq 0x0
section .text
main:
        fld qword[val]
        fsqrt
        fst qword[res]
        xor rax,rax
        mov rdi, float_t
        mov rsi, [res]
        call printf
        mov rax,60
        mov rdi,0
        syscall
```

I assembled it by

```
$  nasm -f elf64 fpu.asm -o fpu.o
```

and then tried to link to glibc with gcc as

```
$  gcc fpu.o -o fpu
```

*GCC* complains with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: fpu.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used
when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What OS (Linux) and version? That error suggests the command line you are using to build the executable (using GCC) is using `-shared` option. You could try building with the `-static` option. I suspect you are using a Linux distro that is based on Ubuntu 16.10 and higher or a recent Debian (a testing version).

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using debian sid.

Comment: Yeah I suspected the possibility of a testing or unstable release. Ubuntu 16.10 and higher (as well as Debian testing and sid) build position independent objects and executable by default (on 64-bit platforms). I would expect building with `-static` may work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, This should be an (accepted) answer.

Comment: There are a boatload of things wrong with this example (which you didn't get a chance to debug yet because you got stuck on linking.)  `printf` takes a `double` by *value* in an XMM reg (with AL=1), not by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Michael Petch in the comments above,

> I would expect building with `-static` may work

I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: `-no-pie`  would be a better choice than `-static`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will have to check that out.  Why is that?

Comment: Because you don't need to statically link libc, bloating the executable and making it harder to find your own code if you look at `objdump -drwC -Mintel` output.  `-no-pie` is sufficient to get the linker to automatically generate PLT stubs and replace `call printf` with `call printf@plt`.  IDK why it doesn't do that for PIE executables; maybe it's a side-effect of the fact that PIE executables are sort of shared libraries.  See also [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)